# Adding button to insert new post in a list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button

I'm trying to add a button that inserts new post on a page. I'm new with jQuery so I'm struggling a little and would like some help. Not getting any kind of errors, it just won`t work as it should be. This is the jQuery as much as I could do it, being at a very beginner level.

```js
$(function() {
  var $newAddButton = $('#newAddButton');
  var $newThought = $('#newThought');
  var $textInput = $('input:text');
  $newAddButton.show();
  $newThought.hide();
  $(#showForm).on('click', function() {
    $newAddButton.hide();
    $newThought.show();
  });
  $newThought.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var newText = $textInput.val();
    $('li:last').after('<li>' + newText + '</li>');
    $newThought.hide();
    $newAddButton.show();
    $textInput.val('');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thought">
  <h2><a href="#">My Thoughts</a></h2>
  <div id="newAddButton"><button href="#" id="showForm">Thought</button></div>
  <form id="newThought">
    <input type="text" id="thoughtDescription" placeholder="Add Thought...">
    <input type="submit" id="addButton" value="add">
  </form>
  <ul>
    <li id="one" class="hot">
      <?php ?>
    </li>
    <li id="two" class="hot">
      <?php ?>
    </li>
    <li id="three" class="hot">
      <?php ?>
    </li>
    <li id="four" class="hot">
      <?php ?>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: "just won`t work as it should be" -- which is what exactly?

Comment: Missing quotes on `$(#showForm).on('click', function() {`

Comment: if you run this on the browser, the console (press F12) might be able to give you a context of what is going on.